# Implicit conversion in C?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

What's going on here:

```
printf("result = %d\n", 1);
printf("result = %f\n", 1);
```

outputs:

```
result = 1
result = 0.000000
```

If I ensure the type of these variables before trying to print them, it works fine of course. Why is the second print statement not getting implicitly converted to 1.00000?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second case you have a mismatch between your format string and the argument type - the result is therefore undefined behavio(u)r.

Comment: +1 for extra letter in "behaviour".  Us Brits use it as backup in case anything nasty happens to the "o".

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Also so that the word has the full set of vowels available.

Comment: @caf: Why can't I find the y? =)

Comment: @Arkku: FYI, and completely off-topic, the word "facetiously" contains all the vowels (including y!) in alphabetical order - there is at least one other word in the English language which has the same property.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the 1 is not converted to 1.0 is that `printf` is “just” a C function with a variable number of arguments, and only the first (required) argument has a specified type (`const char *`). Therefore the compiler “cannot” know that it should be converting the “extra” argument—it gets passed *before* `printf` actually reads the format string and determines that it should get a floating point number.

Now, admittedly your format string is a compile-time constant and therefore the compiler could make a *special case* out of `printf` and *warn* you about incorrect arguments (and, as others have mentioned, some compilers do this, at least if you ask them to). But in the general case it cannot know the specific formats used by arbitrary vararg functions, and it's also possible to construct the format string in complex ways (e.g. at runtime).

To conclude, if you wish to pass a specific type as a “variable” argument, *you* need to cast it.

Comment: Note that for variable arguments, `char` and `short` are promoted to `int` and `float` is promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 2):

An undefined behavior. An int is being treated as float

Comment: ITYM "an int is being treated as a float".

Comment: `printf` is looking for a `double`, actually.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that printf isn't really C++.  Printf is a C function which takes a variable argument list, and applies the provided arguments to the format string basis the types specified in the format string.

If you want any sort of actual type checking, you should use streams and strings - the actual C++ alternatives to good old C-style printf.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, presumably it's fine if your put '1.0'

I suppose the printf only gets the address of the variable, it has no way of knowing what it was. But I would have thought the compiler would have the decency to warn you.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what types the function expecting. This is what makes variadic functions very ray to get wrong

Comment: @Alexander: note that some compilers, e.g. gcc, **do** check the format string for printf *et al* and can emit warnings for mismatches in the number and/or type(s) of the arguments.